# Java frame screenshot showing repaint artifacts

Tags: java, swing, jframe, screenshot, repaint

I'm performing screen shots of my app's `JFrame`, but often a drawing artefact shows up, such as an image in my frame in the upper-left corner (not where it normally is), because I believe it's catching it during a repaint.

Any way around this? I've tried adding a 1/2 second delay after a `repaint()` hoping it would stay finished, but didn't work (though problems occurred less often). I've got multiple controls on the frame repainting as they see fit. I've also set a flag to prevent programmatic repainting with the time delay, but problems still creep in.

I'm using the following code for the screenshot:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
this.paint(img.getGraphics());
File outputfile = new File(saveImageName);
ImageIO.write(img, ext, outputfile);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add a complete [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Don't use `paint`, use `printAll`

Comment: Where does this code takes place? Please give [mcve]

Comment: Plus 10 to the MRE, but why not use [`Robot.createScreenCapture(Rectangle)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)) instead? Quite robust.

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer! Very easy fix much better results with the title bar now!

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson, I looked at that previously, but this looked cleaner, excellent now with using printAll instead.